# Scrapy register a custom clean line by line item exporter

Tags: scrapy

So, this should have been simpler, and in the end it was quite simple, but the Scrapy documentations do leave some finding out to do ... So anyway this is a Q + A:

How to right Scrapy items "as is" line by line to a text file?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to register an item exporter, and then tell Scrapy that you want to use it from command line:

1. Create a file named: lines_exporter.py:

```
from scrapy.exporters import BaseItemExporter
from scrapy.utils.python import to_bytes

class LinesExporter(BaseItemExporter):
    def __init__(self, file, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(dont_fail=True, **kwargs)
        self.file = file
        self._kwargs.setdefault('ensure_ascii', not self.encoding)

    def export_item(self, item):
        itemdict = dict(self._get_serialized_fields(item))
        data = ', '.join(itemdict.values()) + '\n'
        self.file.write(to_bytes(data, self.encoding))
```

2. Add/edit the following in your settings.py:

```
FEED_EXPORTERS = {
    'lines': 'project_name.lines_exporter.LinesExporter',
}
```

3. When invoking Scrapy from command line, specify the output-format flag, or:

```
-t lines
```

Enjoy!